# DOMPDF hangs when table spans pages

Tags: php, dompdf

I updated from dompdf 0.5 to 0.6 b3 in order to get better support of some CSS I'd like to
use when generating a PDF in an application.

In the old code version, my current page generation worked fine - one table spanned multiple pages with no problem.

But in the new version, DOMPDF hangs once the code tries to generate a PDF where a table spans onto another page.

My error logs give me

```
PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in 
../sfDomPDFPlugin/lib/dompdf/include/frame.cls.php on line 374...
```

I figure it's a CSS rule, but I'm not clear on what it might be.   Suggestions?

Update:  Here's some example code that fails.  I had to cut it down a bit, 
but it includes you all of the relevant tags.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>PDF</title>
<style type="text/css">
body
{
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
background-image: url('/images/draft_watermark_small.png');
}
th {
font-size: 8pt;
}
#sf_admin_container ul, #sf_admin_container ol, #sf_admin_container li, #sf_admin_container h1, #sf_admin_container h2, #sf_admin_container h3, #sf_admin_container h4, #sf_admin_container h5, #sf_admin_container h6, #sf_admin_container pre, #sf_admin_container form, #sf_admin_container body, #sf_admin_container html, #sf_admin_container p, #sf_admin_container blockquote, #sf_admin_container fieldset, #sf_admin_container input { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#sf_admin_container a img,:link img,:visited img { border: none; }
#sf_admin_container td
{
margin: 0;
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 8px;
background-color: #fff;
padding: 2px;
}
#sf_admin_container p
{
margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#sf_admin_container h1
{
margin: 2px 0pt;
padding: 3px;
padding-left: 0px;
color: #555;
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
font-size: 22px;
}
#sf_admin_container .sf_admin_default_action
{
background-color: #fc6 !important;
font-weight: bold !important;
}
#sf_admin_container .sf_admin_list
{
width: 100%;
border: 1px solid #000;
border-bottom: 1px;
border-right: 1px;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
#sf_admin_container .sf_admin_list th
{
color: #fff;
padding: 2px;
background-color: #900;
text-align: left;
}
#sf_admin_container .sf_admin_list th a
{
color: #333;
}
#sf_admin_container .sf_admin_list td
{
padding: 2px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
#sf_admin_container .sf_admin_filters li
{
list-style-type: none;
}
#sf_admin_container .sf_admin_row_0 td
{
background-color: #eee;
}
#sf_admin_container .sf_admin_row_1 td
{
border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
background-color: #EEF;
}
#sf_admin_container .sf_admin_row_2 td
{
}
#sf_admin_container .sf_admin_row_total td
{
border: 2px solid #000;
}
#sf_admin_container #heading
{
color: #fff;
background-color: #900;
padding: 3px;
font-size: 14pt;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
}
#sf_admin_container #heading-bold
{
font-weight: bold;
}
#sf_admin_container #heading-total
{
color: #fff;
padding: 2px;
background-color: #900;
text-align: left;
}
div.wysiwyg-view h1
{
font-size: 2em; margin: .67em 0;
background-color: transparent !important;
color: #000 !important;
}
div.wysiwyg-view h2
{
font-size: 1.5em; margin: .75em 0;
background-color: transparent !important;
color: #000 !important;
}
div.wysiwyg-view h3
{
font-size: 1.17em; margin: .83em 0;
background-color: transparent !important;
color: #000 !important;
}
div.wysiwyg-view ol, ul, dir,
menu, dd { margin-left: 40px !important;}
div.wysiwyg-view ol { list-style-type: decimal !important; }
div.wysiwyg-view ol ul, ul ol,
ul ul, ol ol { margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; }
div.wysiwyg-view blockquote { margin-left: 40px !important; margin-right: 40px !important;}
#watermark { position: fixed; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; width: 200px; height: 200px; opacity: .5; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="sf_admin_container">
<table width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<img width="500" src="https://test-quote.expedient.com/images/expedient-logo-010313.png">
</td>
<td width="40%" style="border: 1px solid #000;vertical-align: top;padding: 0px;">
<div id="heading" style="font-size: 14pt;vertical-align: top;"> Quotation # 40414 </div>
<br>
<div style="left: 2px;position: relative;">
1050 Hull Street
<br>
Baltimore, MD 21230
<br>
Phone: 410-209-6700
<br>
www.datapointinc.com
<br>
<br>
Date: 03/14/13
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<table class="sf_admin_list" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td id="heading" width="100%" colspan="6">
<b>Sample Quote</b>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="heading-bold" width="40%">
<center> QUOTED FOR </center>
</td>
<td id="heading-bold" width="12%">
<center> SALES REP </center>
</td>
<td id="heading-bold" width="12%">
<center> SALES ENGINEER </center>
</td>
<td id="heading-bold" width="12%">
<center> CONTRACT TERM </center>
</td>
<td id="heading-bold" width="12%">
<center> TERMS </center>
</td>
<td id="heading-bold" width="12%">
<center> EST. DELIVERY </center>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<center> CeraTech (Kim Shumaker) </center>
</td>
<td>
<center> Geoffrey Maddock  </center>
</td>
<td>
<center> Brian Willis </center>
</td>
<td>
<center> 36 Months</center>
</td>
<td>
<center> Net 30</center>
</td>
<td>
<center> 3.00 weeks </center>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table class="sf_admin_list">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th style="width: 1em;">
<center>SKU</center>
</th>
<th style="width: 1em;">
<center>Type</center>
</th>
<th style="width: 1em;">
<center>Quantity</center>
</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th style="width: 4em;">
<center>Unit</center>
</th>
<th style="width: 4em;">
<center>One Time Costs</center>
</th>
<th style="width: 4em;">
<center>Monthly Recurring Cost</center>
</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="topmenu" style="background-color: #ccc;text-align:center;" colspan="7">Cleveland (151)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="submenu" style="background-color: #ddd;text-align:center;" colspan="7">Managed Virtualization</td>
</tr>
<tr class="sf_admin_row_1">
<td width="25px">
<div style="text-align: center;"> 1 </div>
</td>
<td width="25px">
<div style="text-align: center;"> New </div>
</td>
<td width="25px">
<div style="text-align: center;"> 1 </div>
</td>
<td>
<div>
<b>Enterprise Virtual Instance - Level 1</b>
</div>
</td>
<td width="50px" style="text-align: right;">
<div id="lineitem_sale_unit_396047">
<b>0.00</b>
</div>
</td>
<td width="50px" style="text-align: right;">
<div id="lineitem_nrp_total_396047">
<b></b>
</div>
</td>
<td width="50px" style="text-align: right;">
<div id="lineitem_mrp_total_396047">
<b>0.00</b>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="sf_admin_row_2">
<td width="25px"> </td>
<td width="25px"> </td>
<td width="25px"> </td>
<td>
<div id="lineitem_detail_396047" style="color:#333; text-indent: 10px;"> 1Ghz Peak, .5Ghz Average CPU; 1GB RAM</div>
</td>
<td width="50px"> </td>
<td width="50px"> </td>
<td width="50px"> </td>
</tr>
<tr class="sf_admin_row_1">
<td width="25px">
<div style="text-align: center;"> 1 </div>
</td>
<td width="25px">
<div style="text-align: center;"> New </div>
</td>
<td width="25px">
<div style="text-align: center;"> 1 </div>
</td>
<td>
<div>
<b>Enterprise Virtual Instance - Level 1</b>
</div>
</td>
<td width="50px" style="text-align: right;">
<div id="lineitem_sale_unit_396051">
<b>0.00</b>
</div>
</td>
<td width="50px" style="text-align: right;">
<div id="lineitem_nrp_total_396051">
<b></b>
</div>
</td>
<td width="50px" style="text-align: right;">
<div id="lineitem_mrp_total_396051">
<b>0.00</b>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="sf_admin_row_2">
<td width="25px"> </td>
<td width="25px"> </td>
<td width="25px"> </td>
<td>
<div id="lineitem_detail_396051" style="color:#333; text-indent: 10px;"> 1Ghz Peak, .5Ghz Average CPU; 1GB RAM</div>
</td>
<td width="50px"> </td>
<td width="50px"> </td>
<td width="50px"> </td>
</tr>
<tr class="sf_admin_row_1">
<td width="25px">
<div style="text-align: center;"> 2 </div>
</td>
<td width="25px">
<div style="text-align: center;"> New </div>
</td>
<td width="25px">
<div style="text-align: center;"> 1 </div>
</td>
<td>
<div>
<b>Enterprise Virtual Instance Level 1 - Installation</b>
</div>
</td>
<td width="50px" style="text-align: right;">
<div id="lineitem_sale_unit_396048">
<b>0.00</b>
</div>
</td>
<td width="50px" style="text-align: right;">
<div id="lineitem_nrp_total_396048">
<b>0.00</b>
</div>
</td>
<td width="50px" style="text-align: right;">
<div id="lineitem_mrp_total_396048">
<b> </b>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="sf_admin_row_2">
<td width="25px"> </td>
<td width="25px"> </td>
<td width="25px"> </td>
<td>
<div id="lineitem_detail_396048" style="color:#333; text-indent: 10px;"> Per Virtual Instance. Setup and Configuration of Virtual Instance(2 Hours Maximum)</div>
</td>
<td width="50px"> </td>
<td width="50px"> </td>
<td width="50px"> </td>
</tr>
<tr class="sf_admin_row_1">
<td width="25px">
<div style="text-align: center;"> 2 </div>
</td>
<td width="25px">
<div style="text-align: center;"> New </div>
</td>
<td width="25px">
<div style="text-align: center;"> 1 </div>
</td>
<td>
<div>
<b>Enterprise Virtual Instance Level 1 - Installation</b>
</div>
</td>
<td width="50px" style="text-align: right;">
<div id="lineitem_sale_unit_396049">
<b>0.00</b>
</div>
</td>
<td width="50px" style="text-align: right;">
<div id="lineitem_nrp_total_396049">
<b>0.00</b>
</div>
</td>
<td width="50px" style="text-align: right;">
<div id="lineitem_mrp_total_396049">
<b> </b>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="sf_admin_row_2">
<td width="25px"> </td>
<td width="25px"> </td>
<td width="25px"> </td>
<td>
<div id="lineitem_detail_396049" style="color:#333; text-indent: 10px;"> Per Virtual Instance. Setup and Configuration of Virtual Instance(2 Hours Maximum)</div>
</td>
<td width="50px"> </td>
<td width="50px"> </td>
<td width="50px"> </td>
</tr>
<tr class="sf_admin_row_1">
<td width="25px">
<div style="text-align: center;"> 4 </div>
</td>
<td width="25px">
<div style="text-align: center;"> New </div>
</td>
<td width="25px">
<div style="text-align: center;"> 1 </div>
</td>
<td>
<div>
<b>Enterprise Virtual Instance Level 2 - Installation</b>
</div>
</td>
<td width="50px" style="text-align: right;">
<div id="lineitem_sale_unit_396050">
<b>0.00</b>
</div>
</td>
<td width="50px" style="text-align: right;">
<div id="lineitem_nrp_total_396050">
<b>0.00</b>
</div>
</td>
<td width="50px" style="text-align: right;">
<div id="lineitem_mrp_total_396050">
<b> </b>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="sf_admin_row_2">
<td width="25px"> </td>
<td width="25px"> </td>
<td width="25px"> </td>
<td>
<div id="lineitem_detail_396050" style="color:#333; text-indent: 10px;"> Per Virtual Instance. Setup and Configuration of Virtual Instance(2 Hours Maximum)</div>
</td>
<td width="50px"> </td>
<td width="50px"> </td>
<td width="50px"> </td>
</tr>
<tr class="sf_admin_row_1">
<td width="25px">
<div style="text-align: center;"> 5 </div>
</td>
<td width="25px">
<div style="text-align: center;"> New </div>
</td>
<td width="25px">
<div style="text-align: center;"> 1 </div>
</td>
<td>
<div>
<b>Enterprise Virtual Instance - Level 3</b>
</div>
</td>
<td width="50px" style="text-align: right;">
<div id="lineitem_sale_unit_396052">
<b>0.00</b>
</div>
</td>
<td width="50px" style="text-align: right;">
<div id="lineitem_nrp_total_396052">
<b></b>
</div>
</td>
<td width="50px" style="text-align: right;">
<div id="lineitem_mrp_total_396052">
<b>0.00</b>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="sf_admin_row_2">
<td width="25px"> </td>
<td width="25px"> </td>
<td width="25px"> </td>
<td>
<div id="lineitem_detail_396052" style="color:#333; text-indent: 10px;"> 3Ghz Peak, 1.5Ghz Average CPU; 3GB RAM</div>
</td>
<td width="50px"> </td>
<td width="50px"> </td>
<td width="50px"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="topmenu" style="background-color: #ccc;text-align:center;" colspan="7">Baltimore - 1050 Hull St.</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="submenu" style="background-color: #ddd;text-align:center;" colspan="7">Managed Virtualization</td>
</tr>
<tr class="sf_admin_row_1">
<td width="25px">
<div style="text-align: center;"> 7 </div>
</td>
<td width="25px">
<div style="text-align: center;"> New </div>
</td>
<td width="25px">
<div style="text-align: center;"> 1 </div>
</td>
<td>
<div>
<b>Enterprise Virtual Instance - Level 4</b>
</div>
</td>
<td width="50px" style="text-align: right;">
<div id="lineitem_sale_unit_396024">
<b>0.00</b>
</div>
</td>
<td width="50px" style="text-align: right;">
<div id="lineitem_nrp_total_396024">
<b></b>
</div>
</td>
<td width="50px" style="text-align: right;">
<div id="lineitem_mrp_total_396024">
<b>0.00</b>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="sf_admin_row_2">
<td width="25px"> </td>
<td width="25px"> </td>
<td width="25px"> </td>
<td>
<div id="lineitem_detail_396024" style="color:#333; text-indent: 10px;"> 4Ghz Peak, 2Ghz Average CPU; 4GB RAM (File)</div>
</td>
<td width="50px"> </td>
<td width="50px"> </td>
<td width="50px"> </td>
</tr>
<tr class="sf_admin_row_1">
<td width="25px">
<div style="text-align: center;"> 8 </div>
</td>
<td width="25px">
<div style="text-align: center;"> New </div>
</td>
<td width="25px">
<div style="text-align: center;"> 1 </div>
</td>
<td>
<div>
<b>Enterprise Virtual Instance Level 4 - Installation</b>
</div>
</td>
<td width="50px" style="text-align: right;">
<div id="lineitem_sale_unit_396025">
<b>0.00</b>
</div>
</td>
<td width="50px" style="text-align: right;">
<div id="lineitem_nrp_total_396025">
<b>0.00</b>
</div>
</td>
<td width="50px" style="text-align: right;">
<div id="lineitem_mrp_total_396025">
<b> </b>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="sf_admin_row_2">
<td width="25px"> </td>
<td width="25px"> </td>
<td width="25px"> </td>
<td>
<div id="lineitem_detail_396025" style="color:#333; text-indent: 10px;"> Per Virtual Instance. Setup and Configuration of Virtual Instance(2 Hours Maximum)</div>
</td>
<td width="50px"> </td>
<td width="50px"> </td>
<td width="50px"> </td>
</tr>
<tr class="sf_admin_row_1">
<td width="25px">
<div style="text-align: center;"> 396 </div>
</td>
<td width="25px">
<div style="text-align: center;"> New </div>
</td>
<td width="25px">
<div style="text-align: center;"> 1 </div>
</td>
<td>
<div>
<b>Enterprise Virtual Instance - Level 8</b>
</div>
</td>
<td width="50px" style="text-align: right;">
<div id="lineitem_sale_unit_396045">
<b>0.00</b>
</div>
</td>
<td width="50px" style="text-align: right;">
<div id="lineitem_nrp_total_396045">
<b></b>
</div>
</td>
<td width="50px" style="text-align: right;">
<div id="lineitem_mrp_total_396045">
<b>0.00</b>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="sf_admin_row_2">
<td width="25px"> </td>
<td width="25px"> </td>
<td width="25px"> </td>
<td>
<div id="lineitem_detail_396045" style="color:#333; text-indent: 10px;"> 8Ghz Peak, 4Ghz Average CPU; 8GB RAM</div>
</td>
<td width="50px"> </td>
<td width="50px"> </td>
<td width="50px"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="submenu" style="background-color: #ddd;text-align:center;" colspan="7">Shared Managed Firewall</td>
</tr>
<tr class="sf_admin_row_1">
<td width="25px">
<div style="text-align: center;"> 168 </div>
</td>
<td width="25px">
<div style="text-align: center;"> New </div>
</td>
<td width="25px">
<div style="text-align: center;"> 1 </div>
</td>
<td>
<div>
<b>Managed Firewall - Level 2</b>
</div>
</td>
<td width="50px" style="text-align: right;">
<div id="lineitem_sale_unit_396030">
<b>0.00</b>
</div>
</td>
<td width="50px" style="text-align: right;">
<div id="lineitem_nrp_total_396030">
<b></b>
</div>
</td>
<td width="50px" style="text-align: right;">
<div id="lineitem_mrp_total_396030">
<b>0.00</b>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="sf_admin_row_2">
<td width="25px"> </td>
<td width="25px"> </td>
<td width="25px"> </td>
<td>
<div id="lineitem_detail_396030" style="color:#333; text-indent: 10px;"> 3 Mbps Sustained Bandwidth, 2 VLAN's, Up to 20 Rules</div>
</td>
<td width="50px"> </td>
<td width="50px"> </td>
<td width="50px"> </td>
</tr>
<tr class="sf_admin_row_1">
<td width="25px">
<div style="text-align: center;"> 169 </div>
</td>
<td width="25px">
<div style="text-align: center;"> New </div>
</td>
<td width="25px">
<div style="text-align: center;"> 1 </div>
</td>
<td>
<div>
<b>Managed Firewall - Level 2 - Setup and Configuration</b>
</div>
</td>
<td width="50px" style="text-align: right;">
<div id="lineitem_sale_unit_396018">
<b>0.00</b>
</div>
</td>
<td width="50px" style="text-align: right;">
<div id="lineitem_nrp_total_396018">
<b>0.00</b>
</div>
</td>
<td width="50px" style="text-align: right;">
<div id="lineitem_mrp_total_396018">
<b> </b>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="sf_admin_row_2">
<td width="25px"> </td>
<td width="25px"> </td>
<td width="25px"> </td>
<td>
<div id="lineitem_detail_396018" style="color:#333; text-indent: 10px;"> Managed Firewall Configuration (2 hours maximum)</div>
</td>
<td width="50px"> </td>
<td width="50px"> </td>
<td width="50px"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="submenu" style="background-color: #ddd;text-align:center;" colspan="7">Colocation and Data Center Connectivity</td>
</tr>
<tr class="sf_admin_row_1">
<td width="25px">
<div style="text-align: center;"> 221 </div>
</td>
<td width="25px">
<div style="text-align: center;"> New </div>
</td>
<td width="25px">
<div style="text-align: center;"> 3 </div>
</td>
<td>
<div>
<b>Mbps Dedicated Internet Access to Colocation - Burstable</b>
</div>
</td>
<td width="50px" style="text-align: right;">
<div id="lineitem_sale_unit_396020">
<b>0.00</b>
</div>
</td>
<td width="50px" style="text-align: right;">
<div id="lineitem_nrp_total_396020">
<b></b>
</div>
</td>
<td width="50px" style="text-align: right;">
<div id="lineitem_mrp_total_396020">
<b>0.00</b>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="sf_admin_row_2">
<td width="25px"> </td>
<td width="25px"> </td>
<td width="25px"> </td>
<td>
<div id="lineitem_detail_396020" style="color:#333; text-indent: 10px;"> Sustained Internet Access burstable to 10Mbps ($150/Mbps)</div>
</td>
<td width="50px"> </td>
<td width="50px"> </td>
<td width="50px"> </td>
</tr>
<tr class="sf_admin_row_1">
<td colspan="4"></td>
<td width="50px">
<center>
<b>TOTAL</b>
</center>
</td>
<td id="heading-total" width="50px" style="text-align: right;">
<div id="lineitem_nrp_grand">$0.00</div>
</td>
<td id="heading-total" width="50px" style="text-align: right;">
<div id="lineitem_mrp_grand">$0.00</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div style="border: 1px solid #000;padding: 5px; margin-right: 3px; font-size: 8px;">
<div class="wysiwyg-view"> </div>
All product, service and pricing information is based on latest information available.
<br>
Subject to change without notice or obligation. Quote subject to, and not inclusive of, applicable shipping, handling and tax.
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Without seeing the HTML it's hard to deduce. You might check anywhere you've set a height and try decreasing it slightly.

Comment: Understood, I'll see about grabbing an example.  I don't have a height value set anywhere, however.

Comment: I don't see anything that would cause an issue. I tried running the code through dompdf 0.6.0 beta 3 and didn't have any trouble. Though I did have trouble with the latest, unreleased code. Not sure where the problem lies.

Comment: I suspect the problem relates to an issue where dompdf is unable to split an element across pages, but nothing about your document appears to relate to anything we've found to be a problem historically. Since you're fairly specific in your table width definition you might just split the table into multiple tables, if this is feasible.

Comment: Yyou are right about it being related to page splitting on some level.  But it's really weird.  If I supply some slightly different content, SOMETIMES it will print two pages successfully.  I tweaked the cellspacing and got some others to work, but still not all.  I imagine it has to do with the overall calculated height of something pushing across to the second table, but I don't know exactly how.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Brian S.   He mentioned that it worked for him with 0.6.0 beta 3, but not the latest, unreleased code.  That made me double check, and it looks like I HAD swapped in the latest code to test something.   Reverting back to that release version, I got this working.

Comment: Still dunno why it fails on the latest code, but I'm glad we got you up-and-running for now.

Comment: We've recently made a change to the git repo that I *believe* addresses the issue. If you have time it's be great if you could try it out and report back.

Comment: I'll be able to try it at some point in the next week or so, hopefully.